# Regex to detect numbers at start of string.

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, consisting of:
some numbers, 
a single letter, 
some numbers and letters.

For example: `987342j34kj3`

I want to output something like:

```
$numbers = 987342
$letter = j
$restofit = 34kj3
```

Any idea how to do this with PHP? Can I use preg_match?

Comment: So, to clarify, your pattern is "some numbers, a letter, something which is letters and numbers"?

Comment: where is the letter k coming from? Is this consistent or is is that an arbitrary match? (How do you want it divided?)

Comment: @Brad: Hopefully a typo.

Comment: Sorry, yes! typo, well caught.  corrected.

Comment: Was confused how you skipped over the first j for k, then back to it. @BoltClock has the answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)([a-z])([a-z0-9]+)/', $string, $matches);

// First element of $matches is the entire matched string, ignore it
list(, $numbers, $letter, $restofit) = $matches;
```

Comment: Except @David19801 skips over the first j and numbers 3&4. This will catch "987342", "k", then the rest of "34kj3".

Comment: I just caught the end delimiter not there.  Thanks :)
The k was a typo, corrected to j as you noticed correctly!

Comment: Remember if you need to match both uppercase and lowercase characters, slap an `i` modifier onto your regex.

Comment: Tried just now, works perfect, confirmed.  Thanks a million.  Needed the i too, but that was my fault not mentioning in the question.  will tick once times up.